# Only make HEAD request when using crawling framework Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

When using the crawling framework Scrapy in Python, I want only to check the HTML response codes of a few thousand domains - and nothing else to do a fast and efficient initial crawling for status code.

How can I only do HEAD Requests instead of the default GET request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the method option in `Request`

```py
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url,
        method="HEAD"
    )
```